# bash script loop to check if variable contains string - not working

Tags: bash, loops

i have a script which copy files from one s3 bucket to local server, do some stuff and upload it to another s3 bucket.
in the original bucket i have few folders, one of them called "OTHER"
i dot want my script to work on this folder
i tried to define a loop to check if the path string does not contains the string "OTHER" only then to continue to other commands but for some reason it is not working.
what am i doing wrong ?

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

       gcs3='s3://gc-reporting-pud-production/splunk_printer_log_files/'
       gcs3ls=$((aws s3 ls 's3://gc-reporting-pud-production/splunk_printer_log_files/' --recursive) | sed 's/^.*\(splunk_printer.*\)/\1/g'| tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '_')
       ssyss3=s3://ssyssplunk
       tokenFile=/splunkData/GCLogs/tokenFile.txt
       nextToken=$((aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "gc-reporting-pud-production" --prefix splunk_printer_log_files/ --max-items 5) |grep -o 'NEXTTOKEN.*' |awk -F " " '{print $2}')
        newToken=$( tail -n 1 /splunkData/GCLogs/tokenFile.txt )
        waterMark=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "gc-reporting-pud-production" --prefix splunk_printer_log_files/ --max-items 5  --starting-token 
       $newToken|sed 's/^.*\(splunk_printer.*zip\).*$/\1/'|sed '1d'|sed '$d')
 while true; do
        for j in $waterMark ; do
                echo $j
                if [ "$j" != *"OTHER"* ]; then
                        gcRegion=$(echo $j |  awk  -F'/' '{print $2}')
                        echo "gcRegion:"$gcRegion
                        if [ "$gcRegion" != "OTHER" ]; then
                                gcTech=$(echo $j | awk  -F'/' '{print $3}')
                                echo "GCTech:"$gcTech
                                gcPrinterFamily=$(echo $j | awk  -F'/' '{print $4}')
                                echo "gcPrinterFamily:" $gcPrinterFamily
                                gcPrinterType=$(echo $j | awk  -F'/' '{print $5}')
                                echo "gcPrinterType:" $gcPrinterType
                                gcPrinterName=$(echo $j| awk -F'/' '{print $6}')
                                echo "gcPrinterName:" $gcPrinterName
                                gcFileName=$(echo $j| awk -F'/' '{print $7}'| awk -F'.zip' '{print $1}')
                                echo "gcFileName:" $gcFileName
                                cd /splunkData/GCLogs

 dir="/splunkData/GCLogs/$gcRegion/$gcTech/$gcPrinterFamily/$gcPrinterType/$gcPrinterName"
                                echo "dir:"$dir
                                mkdir -p  $dir
                                aws s3 sync $gcs3$gcRegion/$gcTech/$gcPrinterFamily/$gcPrinterType/$gcPrinterName/  $dir
                                find $dir  -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -o -d "${0%.*}" "$0"' '{}' ';'
                                aws s3 cp $dir $ssyss3/$gcRegion/$gcTech/$gcPrinterFamily/$gcPrinterType/$gcPrinterName/ --recursive --exclude "*.zip"


                                newToken=$( tail -n 1 /splunkData/GCLogs/tokenFile.txt )
                                nextToken=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "gc-reporting-pud-production" --prefix splunk_printer_log_files/ --max-items 5 --starting-token $newToken |grep -o 'NEXTTOKEN.*' |awk -F " " '{print $2}')
                                 waterMark=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket "gc-reporting-pud-production" --prefix splunk_printer_log_files/ --max-items 5  --starting-token $newToken|sed 's/^.*\(splunk_printer.*zip\).*$/\1/'|sed '1d'|sed '$d')
                                echo "$nextToken" > "$tokenFile"
                        fi
                fi
        done


done
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net tells you all you need to know for your question.

Comment: For example, you can't use `$((cmd) | cmd)`; it has to be `$(cmd | cmd)`.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply
i used this site, changed all what suggested but still same results..

Comment: When you say "same results", we can't know what that means, because all you describe is "not working". Do you get an error? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the double-bracket conditional command to turn `==` and `!=` into **pattern matching** operators:

```
if [[ "$j" != *"OTHER"* ]]; then
#  ^^                   ^^
```

Or use `case`

```
case "$j" in
*OTHER*) ... ;;
*) echo "this is like an `else` block" ;;
esac
```

Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ for other things to fix.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, 
i tried this option but it is still not working

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck with it. Unless you care to share some details.

Comment: i changed the loop to be: if [[ "$j" != OTHER ]]; then this is the path: splunk_printer_log_files/OTHER/FDM/OTHER/Dimension Elite/P13851/2019-04-18T16:13:41.698Z_1.91.0.192_1.88.0.0_10.1.3810.zip obviously it is contains the string "OTHER" but instead of quit the loop it continue the rest of the code

Comment: @sarit You have to use `!= *OTHER*` for partial matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think glenn jackman was on the right path.  Try this:

```
if [[ "$j" != *OTHER* ]]; then
```

The [[ ]] is required for pattern string matching (and you have to remove the " ).  The case statement is also a good idea.  You can abandon the shell test altogether and use grep as follows:

```
if 
  grep -q '.*OTHER.*' <<< "$j" 2>/dev/null
then
  ...
fi
```

Here's a check of the [[ ]]:

```
$ echo $j
abOTHERc

$ [[ "$j" == *OTHER* ]]

$ echo $?
0
```

As per BenjaminW., the quotes around $j in [[ ]] are unnecessary.  However, the quotes around `*OTHER*` do make a big difference.  See below:

```
$ j="OTHER THINGS"
$ [[ $j == "*OTHER*" ]] ; echo "$j" matches '"*OTHER*"': $?
OTHER THINGS matches "*OTHER*": 1

$ [[ $j == *OTHER* ]] ; echo "$j" matches '*OTHER*': $?
OTHER THINGS matches *OTHER*: 0
```

Comment: i changed the loop to be:

if [[ "$j" != *OTHER* ]]; then

this is the path:
splunk_printer_log_files/OTHER/FDM/OTHER/Dimension Elite/P13851/2019-04-18T16:13:41.698Z_1.91.0.192_1.88.0.0_10.1.3810.zip

obviously it is contains the string "OTHER"
but instead of quit the loop it continue the rest of the code

Comment: Did you really remove the asterisks?  It should be [[ "$j" != *OTHER* ]] if you want that logic.

Comment: The quotes don't matter here. The left side is quoted anyway in `[[ ]]`, so they have no effect; on the right side, they're 'just surrouding a fixed string and have no effect either.

Comment: @sarit, there is formatting in commands: surrounding a word with asterisks produces italics. Use backticks around your code to show it exactly.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - You are half right - the quotes around $j don't matter - `[[ ]]` does the job there.  However,  `"*OTHER*"` is definitely different than *OTHER*.  That's the whole point of my post.  I'll  edit to provide an example.

Comment: Yes, I meant that `*"OFFER"*` and `*OFFER*` makes no difference.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  pls look at my last edit.  There is a BIG difference between those two with bash on MacOS (and my experience on CentOS is the same).    Let me know if your test results differ.

Comment: I have the `*` outside of the double quotes, did you see that? I think you're assuming I have them inside.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  You are absolutely right - there is no difference between `*"OFFER"*` and `*OFFER*`.   Thanks for pointing that out.  Looks like @glenn jackman had it right from the beginning.